# KendoDateTimePicker the drop-down list will consist only two entries

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-datetimepicker

KendoDateTimePicker the drop-down list will consist only two entries - "9:30 AM" and "14:30 PM"

Comment: So what is the question, exactly ?

Comment: If you only need 2 values, wouldn't it make sense to have a radio button group? Even a simple `select` would do the job and it would not require the additional JavaScript needed to run the DatePicker...

Comment: dropdown list should consist of only two entries, $("#timepicker").kendoDateTimePicker({
  value: new Date(2000,10,1),
    dates: [
        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0),
        new Date(2000, 10, 10, 10, 30, 0)
    ] 
});   correct this code, thanks

Comment: So, you want a dropDownList with two options, and when the user selects one, the datepicker gets that selected value. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, first choose the day, then the time of the two options, I translate the text, you can specify if something is not clear

Answer (score 0):

With Kendo [`DateTimePicker`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datetimepicker) you can select the `min` and `max` dates but not a time range for each day **BUT** you can do it with [`TimePicker`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/timepicker).

Maybe you can decompose your UI in [`DatePicker`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/datepicker) and `TimePicker` and then choose [`max`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/timepicker#max-datedefault) and [`min`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/timepicker#min-datedefault) for conforming your time range.